# How to force const propagation through an inline function?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, constexpr

I'm trying to coerce the pre-processor to perform some math for me so a constant gets propagated into inline assembly. Here's the reduced case:

```c
inline
unsigned int RotateRight(unsigned char value, unsigned int amount)
{
    COMPILE_ASSERT(((unsigned char)(amount%32)) < 32);
    __asm__ ("rorb %1, %0" : "+mq" (value) : "I" ((unsigned char)(amount%32)));
    return value;
}
```

The code above relies upon CPU specific functionality, and I'm OK with it (its actually a template specialization on x86/x64 Linux when GCC is available). The ***`"I"`*** constraint says the integral value must be between `[0,31]` inclusive.

Callers of the code would look like:

```c
byte b1 = RotateRight(1, 1);
byte b2 = RotateRight(1, 31);
```

A `RotateRight(1, 31)` comes from the cryptographers (its undefined behavior in C/C++ because a byte can only be rotated in the range `[0,7]`). I can break free from C/C++ constraints using ASM. And since the shift amount is known at compile time, I'd like it to be reduced at compile time; and I'd like the `rorb` version using the immediate-8 generated.

Without the `COMPILE_ASSERT`, the code compiles but I'm not sure if the constant is being propagated. That is, it might be generated with an unexpected reduction (`% 32`). With the `COMPILE_ASSERT`, the code fails to compile.

```
$ make validat1.o
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -march=native -pipe -c validat1.cpp
In file included from simple.h:10:0,
                 from filters.h:6,
                 from files.h:5,
                 from validat1.cpp:6:
misc.h: In function ‘T CryptoPP::rotlFixed(T, unsigned int) [with T = unsigned char]’:
misc.h:940:43: error: ‘y’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
  CRYPTOPP_COMPILE_ASSERT(((unsigned char)(y%32)) < 32);
                                           ^
misc.h:72:85: note: in definition of macro ‘CRYPTOPP_COMPILE_ASSERT_INSTANCE’
 _COMPILE_ASSERT_INSTANCE(assertion, instance) static CompileAssert<(assertion)>
```

I know I'm not supposed to use a `#define`, and C++ inline functions are the answer. But I feel like I'm suffering a disconnect.

How do I force the compiler to propagate the value that involves `const` values?

Or, if the `COMPILE_ASSERT` is the wrong tool (`const` is being propagated), how do I set up a test so that I can verify the immediate-8 version of the `rorb` is used?

---

Related, this is a C++03 project. It does not use Boost, does not use Cmake, does not use Autotools, etc.

Comment: The shift amount is limited in C and C++ because the hardware masks the shift count. Using assembly doesn't change that.

Comment: @Bo - agreed, but I'm not bound by C/C++ undefined behavior. If I reduce the constant at compile time or I place the shift amount in CX, then I get the reduction to the low order 5 bits for free. And its well defined in ASM, and not subject to removal like in C/C++.

Comment: My MinGW compiler says *x* is undefined (at return statement). Is it OK?

Comment: Also, isn't *amount%32* always less than 32 for unsigned *amount*?

Comment: @stgatilov  - yes, it always should be. But I don't know how to construct a test to ensure the reduction is occurring at compile time. Hence the reason I asked: *"...how do I set up a test so that I can verify the immediate-8 version of the `rorb` is used?"*

Comment: It seems to me that expression with compile-time constant arguments should be compile-time constant automatically. Nevertheless, you can use static const as in my updated answer if you are not yet sure.

Comment: Try this: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {char c = 9; asm("rorb %1, %0" : "+mq" (c) : "I" (argc)); return c;}` Since 'I' requires a constant, this gets a compile error (impossible constraint). Changing `(argc)` to `(3)` compiles correctly. IOW, if somehow during the compile+inlining of your RotateRight amount is not a constant, the compile will fail. (FYI: If somehow RotateRight isn't inlined, it will also fail). So, will `rorb $<constant integer>, <something>` always get assembled to immediate-8?  Can't think why it wouldn't. It's not like the assembler is going to add a `mov cx`.

Answer (score 4):

When you specify *amount* as function argument, you lose its compile-time constness.

Why don't you declare *amount* is template argument? In such case the function user is also forced to pass a compile-time constant, which is good too.

To ensure that shift is used as compile-time constant, you can create a static const local variable.

```
template<unsigned int amount> inline
unsigned int RotateRight(unsigned char value)
{
    static const unsigned char shift = (unsigned char)(amount%32);
    __asm__ ("rorb %1, %0" : "+mq" (value) : "I" (shift));
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea. Let me try it. I'm working on another problem at the moment, so I need some time to change the source code.

Comment: So I looked at the impact of the changes by adding an additional template argument. (Currently, `RotateLeft` and `RotateRight` is a template based on word size). I don't think I am going to be able to make the change. I'll tuck it away for a future change, like a major version upgrade of the library.

Comment: @jww Any specific reason?
In C++03 there is no constexpr, so if you pass *amount* as function argument, the language will always treat it as not a compile-time constant, and you are left on the mercy of the optimizer (which is never guaranteed).

Comment: *"Any specific reason?"* - its a public library ([Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/)), and it would be a breaking ABI change. Our governance allows us to move an ABI forward with a minor increment (i.e., 5.6.2 to 5.7). "Moving forward" means *not* breaking existing user code. But to completely break the ABI, we need a major version bump (i.e., 5.6.2 to 6.0). We are not ready for 6.0 just yet.

Comment: Regarding making it a template parameter, checkout the comment at [LLVM Bug 24226 - Constant not propagated into inline assembly, results in "constraint 'I' expects an integer constant expression"](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24226): *"I've been bitten by this in the past. IIRC, in the past when I ran into this, even a constexpr expression or a template argument didn't help"*.